# overloaded based on constness

Tags: c++, constants

I'm reading Essential C++. In the section 4.3, the author gives an example to
explain the usage of **const**

```
class val_class {
public:
    val_class(const BigClass &v)
        : _val(v) {}

    const BigClass& val() const {return _val;}
    BigClass& val() {return _val;}
};

void example(const BigClass *pbc, BigClass &rbc)
{
    pbc->val();
    rbc.val();
}
```

In the above code segment, the author overloads the function val based on constness.
And then the `pbc->val()` will invoke const instance, `rbc.val()` will invoke non-const instance.

The *pbc* is a const pointer of type **BigClass**. How can we guarantee that the **BigClass** has a member function *val* ? Should the **BigClass** be replaced with **val_class** in the example function?

Comment: I think your `Const` supposed to be `const`.

Comment: Based on what's given, it's hard to say what's going on.  It's incomplete because `val_class` doesn't inherit anything and has declared no field named `_val`.  If the book doesn't give anything more, then it's just a bad example or a typo.  If you have a complete definition of `BigClass`, please include that as well.  Also, capital-C `Const` is probably meant to be `const`, unless that has a special definition somewhere too?

Comment: Also what is declaration of _val.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must be this: [Your Full Example](http://books.google.com/books?id=PQBDY5PHRxMC&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=val_class+BigClass&source=bl&ots=5d1D2BPtac&sig=IEkyx0Puwk4KAi6p94TOIV-yFso&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Rn4LUIqEGaPW2gWCh9Ex&ved=0CGcQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=val_class%20BigClass&f=false)

This is obviously just a typo in the book. As you figured out for yourself, the `example` function should look as follows

```
void example(const val_class *pbc, val_class &rbc)
{
    pbc->val();
    rbc.val();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Must be replaced since `BigClass` cannot be derived from `val_class` (`val_class` cannot store `reference` or `const-reference` to `BigClass` object, because code will not compilable in this case, so it can store only `BigClass` object and then `BigClass` cannot be derived from `val_class` because cannot store object of undeclared/non-full declared type).